# iOS/Android Minimal Swipe Distance rule/norm

Tags: android, ios, mobile, distance, swipe

I was just wondering if there is a minimal distance for a swipe gesture to be considered a swipe ? Something like 5% of Screen resolution, or some other way of calculating it ? Or is it left at the discretion of the developpers ?

Is there a "globally recognized rule" mentionning this somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "universal" rule for swipes. It doesn't seem to be the case in Android, as when detecting swipes/flings with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float)), the velocities/positions are provided for you to determine whether or not to consume the event.

I personally wouldn't set a minimal distance to a percentage of the screen, as it'll give a fairly different experience between a small phone and a 10'' tablet.